# Can't change AlertDialog items colors

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I created multiple alert dialogs in  different activities. Now all of sudden the AlertDialog items appear in red !

Here is my code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, MyDialogStyle);
    builder.setTitle("Select Method :");
    final String[] choices = new String[]{"Weight Based", "Body Surface Area"};
    builder.setItems(choices, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // the user clicked on choice[which]
            switch (choices[which]) {
                case "Weight": {
                    create_item(false);
                    break;
                }
                case "Body Surface Area": {
                    create_item(true);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    builder.show();
```

styles.xml (v21)

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:text">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceListItemSecondary">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:color">#000000</item>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>\
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:text">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">#000000</item>
</style>
```

I tried changing the parent style or deleting it, but both give the same bright red result ! any ideas ?

Comment: May be this link used for you: https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-spinner-prompt.html

Comment: Didn't help. It's more related to styling spinners.

Answer (score 0):

try use this style ,,, hope it'll work for you

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>
```